# How can i find area of an element in a meshed surface using python

Tags: python, mesh, area, gaussian

I am new to python . So help me in this. I have X,Y,Z coordinates(3D data points), lets say 1000 points, which makes a surface in 3d space. I have to find the total surface area of it.

This can be done by meshing the coordinates within X, Y, Z and then finding the area of each element and summing up.

I have meshed the coordinates in 3d space.

Now what i need is to find the area of each element. Is there any method in python where i can calculate the surface area. 
I was suggested to use Gaussian quadrature method to do it. But i din get how to use it in python to get the area.

Can anyone help me in finding the area of the surface using python.

Any help is thankful.

Comment: You say you have already meshed the vertices. Does your mesh consist of triangles? If so, is your actual question how to calculate the area of a triangle in threedimensional space?

Comment: Easy to do for planar triangles; harder for higher order.  Gaussian quadrature is the best bet.

Comment: Well, sorry, I'm not that mathematically inclined, so Gaussian quadrature is beyond me. On the other hand, calculating the areas of triangles is rather easy, that's why I asked if the mesh consists solely of them. Is Gaussian quadrature still better in that case and why?

Comment: @blubberdiblub no they are not triangles , they are squares.

Comment: If they are actually regular squares (as opposed to irregular quadrangles), calculating the areas of them would be even easier. But squares can't approximate arbitrary closed surfaces in Euclidean space. So either some of my assumption were wrong or you don't have regular Euclidean squares.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gaussian quadrature to calculate the area, either by doing an area integral or by doing a contour integral around the perimeter of each element.

Maybe this will get you started:

http://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~ntg/780/readings/hjorth-jensen_notes2009_07.pdf

I wouldn't wait for someone to hand you Python code.  Better to get a shovel and start digging.